# Vectors/Lists in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am new to SQL, are there list or vector variable types? Can I have a column whose type is a list of strings?

Maybe something like:

```
CREATE TABLE myTbl(domain varchar PRIMARY KEY, linkList list<varchar>);
```

Can I append a string like so(by using the '+=' operator):

```
UPDATE myTbl SET linkList += "www.test.com," WHERE domain="blah";
// Table is like so
CREATE TABLE myTbl(domain varchar PRIMARY KEY, linkList varchar);
// Column linkList is a string of links separated by comma's
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[No, there are no array/list/vector data types in SQLite](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html).  [The string concatenation operator in SQLite is `||`](http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html).

Answer (score 7):

You can store lists in a SQLite field with the json1 extension: https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html

So your schema would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE myTbl(
    domain varchar PRIMARY KEY,
    linkList JSON DEFAULT('[]'));
```

and to append an item:

```
UPDATE myTbl
SET linkList = json_insert(linkList, '$[#]', "www.test.com")
WHERE domain="blah";
```

The SQLite JSON support is quite flexible, particularly with newer versions of SQLite.  You can set up [indices on JSON expressions](https://sqlite.org/expridx.html) for fast matching depending on the contents of your JSON.  You can use it with [generated columns](https://dgl.cx/2020/06/sqlite-json-support) for dynamic data extraction.  You can `SELECT` from a JSON list with the [`json_each()` table valued function](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jeach).

Try copy-pasting this into on the `sqlite3` command line or in https://sqliteonline.com/ :

```sql
CREATE TABLE myTbl(
    domain varchar PRIMARY KEY,
    linkList JSON DEFAULT('[]'));
INSERT INTO myTbl(domain) VALUES ("blah");

UPDATE myTbl
SET linkList = json_insert(linkList, '$[#]', "www.test.com")
WHERE domain="blah";

UPDATE myTbl
SET linkList = json_insert(linkList, '$[#]', "www.example.com")
WHERE domain="blah";

SELECT * FROM myTbl;
```

Note: This example requires SQLite 3.31 for the `$[#]` notation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no list datatype in SQLite.

But you can workaround that limitation:

1. Convert your list to JSON (that includes escaping each element individually),
2. Put the JSON string into your table as [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) (or SQLITE_TEXT if your version of SQLite is before SQLite 3.9).

Obviously, JSON has a big performance impact, and adding an element to your list will take time (read, deserialize, add, serialize, update).

Comment: Why `SQLITE_TEXT` and not [`JSON1`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html)? https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/141907/203416  // in your example might as well store as text (without json serialization) and with a well defined separator?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible in SQLite (probably that is one of the reasons for 'Lite' in the name). Under the hood it only has storage types: 64-bit integer `SQLITE_INTEGER`, 64-bit float (double) `SQLITE_FLOAT`, blob (binary) `SQLITE_BLOB` and string `SQLITE_TEXT`. All SQL types are mapped to these. There is also `SQLITE_NULL`.